# Reverse String in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Input:- 'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.'

Output:- 'peppers. pickled of peck a picked piper peter'

can anyone help this problem

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: There's a very simple answer to this but we'd like to see what you've tried for yourself

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first take the  [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How to ask a good question.

Comment: split those words using space as separator, gets the array of those words and just reverse its order before recomposing the final string

Answer (score 0):

In the following

- `s` is the string `'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.'`;
- `s.split()` returns a list of the "words" in the string `s` where "words" are separated by whitespace: `['peter', 'piper', 'picked', 'a', 'peck', 'of', 'pickled', 'peppers.']` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split));
- `reversed(s.split())` returns a reverse iterator over the list `s.split()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed));
- `next(it).rstrip('.')` returns the first element in the iterator, stripping the period from this element: `'peppers'` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)); we print this out (without ending the print with a newline, which `print` does by default);
- we loop over the remaining elements in the iterator, printing them out (preceded by a space character and without ending the print with a newline).

```
s = 'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.'
it = reversed(s.split())
print(next(it).rstrip('.'), end = "")
for i in it:
     print(f" {i}", end = "")
print('.')
```

Alternatively, we can use the [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of strings as follows:

```
it = reversed(s.split())
print(next(it).rstrip('.'), end = " ")
print(" ".join(it), end = ".\n")
```

Above, `" ".join(it)` evaluates to the concatenation of the elements in `it` (all of which are strings), with a space character separating the elements. That is, it evaluates to the string `"peppers pickled of peck a picked piper peter"`. `end = ".\n"` ensures that after the aforementioned string is printed that we also print a period plus a newline.

**Output**

In either case, the output is

```
peppers pickled of peck a picked piper peter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Split, reverse and join:

```
s = 'peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers.'

print(' '.join(reversed(s.split())))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sentence = "peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers."
#split string by single space
chunks = sentence.split(' ')

s = " "
rev = s.join(reversed(chunks))
  
print(rev)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You probably don't want to shadow the *str* function and you almost certainly don't want to construct strings like that (notwithstanding the fact that you'll have a redundant trailing space). Are you familiar with str.join()?

Comment: @LancelotduLac you're absolutely right, I edited my Answer to reflect your suggestions